# Preview and Save a Client side generated pdf using android webview

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

I am aware of that the fact that android webview doesn't support pdf preview or download but I have googled about other way outs and find out that we can see pdf using Google Doc Viewer using  [this link](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Loading-PDF-in-Android-WebView) but my problem is as below -

1. I am not getting any pdf file(.pdf extension file) from server as on the backend(Website), the pdf is getting generated on client side(on the fly), So how to deal with this situation.
2. Along with the preview, I also want to download the pdf.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Pdf generated client side are you saying mobile end?

Comment: No ,I mean on the website(pdf is getting draw using javascript but not getting pdf url)